# Why is 'top' property ignored when relatively positioning an element with no explicit height?

Tags: css

**I am not looking for a different solution to the question of centering elements; I am looking for an explanation why the solution presented here doesn’t work.**

Consider the following jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/6Xyq8/2/

Here’s the HTML/CSS code for reference:

### HTML

```
<div class='outer'>
    <div class='middle'>
        <div class='inner'>
            Text should be centered
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.outer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #00f;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.middle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.inner {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    top: -50%;
    width: 5em;
}
```

The element inspector in both Chrome and Firefox tell me that both `middle` and `inner` have the correct width and height, and indeed the *horizontal* positioning is working correctly, but for some reason the `top: -50%` rule is ignored. However, it is only ignored if `.middle` doesn’t have an explicit height — if you add one, it works, even if the effective height is the same as what it is already. Why is this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's The Best Way of Centering a Div Vertically with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css)

Comment: @poke: That’s not a duplicate. My question is not what the best way is, but why my solution isn’t working.

Comment: I think this is a well-known problem when setting property of children relative to the ***height*** of the parent. The `height` should be explicitly set. It's not easy to answer why, it's just how CSS is designed.

Comment: The inner div is centered vertically as if it were 3em tall like the middle div.

Comment: It's not centered, because in div.inner you calculate 50% from the height of the div.middle and not from the div.outer.

Comment: @DenisV: Both element inspectors (Chrome and Firefox) show the same height for those two elements.

Comment: @Timwi well, you've changed the link to jsfiddle, but still div.middle height is 32, div.outer is 80.

Comment: @DenisV: Sorry, I misread. Yes, it *should* be the height of div.middle. But it doesn’t, it behaves like top:0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the behavior as as specified in [the old CSS 2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/visuren.html#position-props) (emphasis mine):

> `<percentage>`
>
> The offset is a percentage of the containing block's width (for 'left' or 'right') or height (for 'top' and 'bottom'). For 'top' and 'bottom', **if the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), the percentage value is interpreted like 'auto'.**

In the [current CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#position-props) that restriction [was removed](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/changes.html#q54), so I’d say it’s a cross-browser bug now. Firefox has a very old bug on this [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2992) that was marked as invalid because of the original spec; and there is a [newer bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=260348) here could use some votes to get more attention.

Comment: Yes, and it does not appear to be an accident - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/changes.html#q54

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks, I was looking for that change description and couldn’t find it!

Comment: There is a "new" Firefox bug for this: [Relative positioning with percentages inside auto-height containing block does not work](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=260348). Filed 10 years ago.

Comment: @romkyns I added that link 9 minutes ago to my answer ^^

Answer (score -1):

For those coming after me try to add `display:grid;` on the parent of container

```
<div style="display: grid;">
    <div _ngcontent-serverapp-c11="">
        <video _ngcontent-serverapp-c11="" onloadedmetadata="this.muted=true" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" class="lazy vid-mobi"><source _ngcontent-serverapp-c11="" src="https://cdn3.blablabla.com/gtb/videos/intro_lg.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works for me